# XML schemas: can a complex type contain another complex type as an element?

Tags: xml, xsd

Can an XML complex type contain an element that is of another complex type? If so, how are the sub elements of the contained complex type handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can. Here is a snippet from some arbitrary XSD (ACORD):

```
   <xsd:complexType name="CovOptionXLat_Type">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element ref="Language" minOccurs="0"/>
         <xsd:element ref="ShortName" minOccurs="0"/>
         <xsd:element ref="PlanName" minOccurs="0"/>
         <xsd:element ref="OLifEExtension" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:ID"/>
      <xsd:attribute name="DataRep" type="DATAREP_TYPES"/>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="OLifEExtension" type="OLifEExtension_Type"/>
   <xsd:complexType name="OLifEExtension_Type" mixed="true">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:any processContents="skip" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="VendorCode" use="required" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:attribute name="ExtensionCode" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:attribute name="DataRep" type="DATAREP_TYPES"/>
      <xsd:attribute name="SystemCode" type="xsd:string"/>
   </xsd:complexType>
```

To better visualize the above:

[image]

A complex type can define attributes, text nodes, mixed with other elements, or just elements, or no elements/attributes at all (empty).

A subelement can be simple, complex or anyType. They are to be handled just like any other element. If you're thinking about the root element of an XML document instance, then the difference between a nested element (in a complex type) and document element is that the former can happen as many times as you need, and you can have as many different types and names as you want; whereas for the latter, you can have only one document element.

There are also rules related to how elements may be named and the type they may have (e.g. you may not be able to use the same name with the same type in certain conditions), how element could be combined (choice, sequence, all), the [Unique Particle Attribution](http://www.w3.org/wiki/UniqueParticleAttribution), etc.

If you're looking for an introduction to XSD in general, there are plenty on the internet. If you're used to more formal writing, I find the [XSD primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/) a good reading.